# Force cancel running Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've made a mistake in pipeline configuration and a job task is now stuck, waiting for a console input in a MS hosted ubuntu agent.

I don't care about the pipeline finishing so I canceled the pipeline but the job is still running, doing nothing, wasting number of running agents in the agent pool.

Is there a way to force cancel or shutdown the pipeline running in a hosted agent in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Comment: Do you still have this issue now? The jobs will be canceled according to your timeout settings if the job is blocked for a long time. Please refer to the document about [timeouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#timeouts).  You can try to delete this run if canceling the pipeline does not work. If you still have this issue, please share your pipeline configuration for further troubleshooting.

Comment: Deleting just makes the job disappear from the job list, it is still visible and running in the agent pool. The job timeouted after the default 60 minutes. I configured the timeouts but the pipeline takes 10-15 minutes to finish and I'm actively working on it, possibly going to produce a deadlock again. It would be really nice to be able to force stop the pipeline if I see the pipeline is deadlocked or not going the right direction.

Comment: Can you share your sample of your blocked pipeline so that I can test on my side? I tried to reproduce your issue in another way: condition:always(). Please check if you have set a similar condition. Currently the only way I found is to wait for job timeout. Cancel or delete pipeline also does not work on my side.

Comment: I'm using terraform and I mistakenly forgot to fill in a variable in arguments. Terraform by default prompts for the value in stdin and that is what deadlocks the pipeline. I found that I can avoid the prompt with "-input=false" argument but the problem can be reduced to the single pipeline task like this: "- pwsh: Read-Host 'Tool behaving badly asking for prompts in automation'".

Comment: Hi @Mirek, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: I resorted to use timeouts in every job and change all conditions I use to include "succeeded()", no deadlock has happened so far but I still think AZ DevOps should have a way to kill a deadlocked job.

Comment: @Mirek note that https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655 says "By default, steps, jobs, and stages run if all previous steps/jobs have succeeded. It's as if you specified "condition: succeeded()", so theoretically adding that manually shouldn't have made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, we could set the **job cancel time** value to configure the cancel time, such as set the field value to 1.

Result:

If the job continues to run after we cancel the build, it will automatically cancel after one minute.

Check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me. it kept respawning every time i tried to cancel or delete it. thank you