# Cancel active job in Azure DevOps YML Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

When I click on the cancel button in the Azure DevOps YML pipeline the pipeline is displayed as canceled but the jobs continue to work.

I tried to cancel the work of a job through the Azure DevOps REST API as indicated in this guide [Azure DevOps pipelines: Cancel multiple pending jobs in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62040308/azure-devops-pipelines-cancel-multiple-pending-jobs-in-queue)  but the jobs continue to work

Could you pleas write me how I can cancel the build in the multi-stage YML pipeline. Since I have tests that take an hour and when I see drops in the logs I would like to have a functionality to cancel the build and start a new build and not wait an hour.

Comment: As a workaround, You can set a timeout in your pipeline. Please refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66007572/force-cancel-running-azure-pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

Check your conditions, specifically that you have thought about the use of `succeeded()`. Otherwise the job (or stage or task, etc.) runs implicitly even if previous dependencies were unsuccessful.

Comment: That's not what the docs state: By default, steps, jobs, and stages run if all previous steps/jobs have succeeded. It's as if you specified "condition: succeeded()" - https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655